# Computer won't load desktop after logging in?

Tags: greeter, dual-boot

My computer won't login completely past a black screen with mouse pointer after login. Everything was fine until I updated now I'm missing the clock/calendar from the bar, programs suddenly missing like Pithos but when visiting the [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter), show's it's installed. What in the hell has happened, I need to access this machine for work! I logged into terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and it's not detecting my NIC either (can't reach internet).

Everything works fine in Windows 10.

Comment: I've moved on to Solus 4. No support for major issues like this is a major sticking point for anyone who wants to have a good experience with this distro. This experience has really soured my perception of this distro and I won't be coming back. You're welcome to take my feedback with a grain of salt or use it to improve. Either way, good luck to you.